# FTP doesn't give write access on Windows Server 2008 and IIS7

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008, iis

I have created an FTP using IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008. I have two types of user: Anonymous and Administrator.

What I want is this: Anonymous users only can read files and Administrator can read and write.

To achieve that I set permissions like this:
[image: To achieve that i set permissions like this]

But every time I try to upload files as Administrator I encounter "Access is Denied" Error.

PS: this configuration works properly on windows 10 but I have trouble to get this to work on Windows Server 2008.